# Pact mock server not returning proper CORS headers

Tags: javascript, cors, pact

My Pact mock server is listening in different port from my tests and my pact mock server is running with following configuration:

```
const provider = pact({
consumer: 'myconsumer',
provider: 'myprovider',
port: 8989,
cors: true,
log: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'logs', 'pact.log'),
dir: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'pacts'),
logLevel: 'DEBUG',
spec: 1
});
```

I request the above mock server using 'axios' and the request is matched with one of the interaction i have configured on the provider (as per pact.log). But response always throws error with CORS.

**My pact log has following information:**
Received OPTIONS request for mock service administration endpoint POST /interactions. Returning CORS headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"null","Access-Control-Allow-Headers":"x-pact-mock-service","Access-Control-Allow-Methods":"DELETE, POST, GET, HEAD, PUT, TRACE, CONNECT, PATCH"}.

why is Access-Control-Allow-Origin is null instead of '*'. ?

How can i disable CORS security completely with tests as the final resorts when i use webpack, npm and mocha based tests.?

Answer (score 2):

That CORS flag is slightly misleading. If your app uses CORS then you will still need to tell Pact that it should expect a request for `OPTIONS` as per the cors standard. This is part of the contract and you can't just expect your server to work, so it should be part of your tests.

See https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-js/issues/58 for background.